# Solr cannot rank shorter matched-field higher

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using solr for searching over institution documents... Each document contains multiple fields such as name, city, state, country,....;

I just tried to search for "George Mason University" using the following query:
name: (George Mason University)... Top-two results returned by solr are:

```
    "solr_id": 1964,
    "rg_id": 3298,
    "rg_parent_id": 0,
    "name": "George Mason University",
    "ext_name": "",
    "city": "Fairfax",
    "country": "US",
    "state": "VA",
    "type": "academic",
    "ext_city": "",
    "zip": "22030-4444",
    "_version_": 1474905441958887400,
    "score": 2.1657412

    "solr_id": 288843,
    "rg_id": 304652,
    "rg_parent_id": 888,
    "name": "George Mason University Bookstore",
    "ext_name": "",
    "city": "Fairfax",
    "country": "US",
    "state": "VA",
    "type": "corporate/serv",
    "ext_city": "",
    "zip": "22030",
    "_version_": 1474905459859128300,
    "score": 2.1657412
```

Indeed, the document with longer name (George Mason University Bookstore) gives the same score as to the correct field name... I have also set omitnorms= False to take the normlength into effect... Can anybody please let me know what's wrong with my query? I would appreciate any help and advice in advance...

Regards,

Ali

Comment: Are you using filtered query or query(q or fq)?

Comment: I am using "q" and I have also set omitnorms=False... This is the problem: when I search for name: (university of toronto), it works fine... However, when it goes to four words (university of california berkeley), it fails and returns the same score for these two documents: D1: (University of California Berkeley) and D2: (University of California Berkeley Bookstore); This only happens when I have 3 tokens (except the stopword) in the query...